# Adding tab icons is shrinking the size of the tab and not showing the full icon

Tags: javafx-2, scenebuilder

I'm using the Java Scene Builder 2.0 to create a GUI that uses the tab pane. I've added an Imageview to each tab so I can give them icons instead of text. I set the tabs minimum width and height to 100x100 and they adjust to that size. When I add an imageview to the tab I'm making it's minimum width and height 100x100 but it shrinks the tab size and only shows a part of the icon. This happens when the imageview has a picture and when it doesn't so I don't think it's a problem with the size of the picture.

You can see from this picture the first tab from the left doesn't have an imageview and is the size I want the tabs to be. The second tab has an empty image view and the rest of the tabs have images. I would like the images to be 100x100 and fit in the tabs.

[image]

A Java Scene Builder solution is prefered but I will also *gladly* accept a code solution.

Comment: I had the same issue with javafx-8. Manually setting tabMaxHeight (in addition to the tabMinHeight that I needed to set) fixed the issue. Very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem it was something simple. In the tab pane Layout settings I only changed the min height/width to 100x100 but I left the max height/width to the default which was 1.7976931348623157E308. I didn't notice that number was so small at first and I changed it to 200. Now the images display better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a JavaFX bug to me.

Comment: PS: In my case I was trying to set these values via CSS, and even when `-fx-tab-max-{width|height}` was set the the bug still occurred. Only went away by applying your trick in the FXML.